# How to fill out a form using PHP and XPatch

Tags: php, html, forms

I have this HTML code and I would like it to be automatically filled with parameters taken from the database/table:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 35
            [nr_wyceny] => W/8/01041122/2021
            [nazwa_firmy] => Test
            [adres_firmy] => testowy
            [kraj_firmy] => polska
            [telefon_firmy] => 79280xxxx
            [osoba_firmy] => ja
            [email_firmy] => pow@d.pl
            [data_inwestycji] => 12/12/2020
            [wycena_wstepna] => 
            [wycena_zrzutem] => on
            [jakosc_niska] => on
            [jakosc_srednia] => 
            [jakosc_wysoka] => 
            [wygoda_mala] => on
            [wygoda_srednia] => 
            [wygoda_maksymalna] => 
            [cena_niska] => on
            [cena_srednia] => 
            [cena_wysoka] => 
            [wydajnosc_niska] => 
            [wydajnosc_srednia] => 
            [wydajnosc_wysoka] => on
            [srodki_wlasne] => on
            [finansowanie_zewnetrzne] => 
            [finansowanie_niepodane] => 
            [dzialalnosc_uslugowa] => on

... //more data
```

The point is that I download an array with the names and values of input fields from the database, if there is a checkbox then the value is on or null if there is input type text then it should have a value, but I don't know how to fill in the form using XPatch - possibly some other method to fill it this form, without rewriting the code. I have a lot of values to fill in and would like to do it automatically. i know how to do it the other way, but i would like to use xpatch and a DOM parser

```
<form action="/xxxxxx.php" method="post" id="xForm" >
<div class="tabela">
<div id="sekcja1" class="sekcja">
<div class="headerx"><p><b>Dane klienta</b></p></div>
<p>Nazwa firmy: <input class="xForm"  type="text" name="nazwa_firmy" value=""/>
<p>Adres: <input class="xForm"  type="text" name="adres_firmy" value=""/>
<p>Kraj: <input class="xForm"  type="text" name="kraj_firmy" value=""/>
<p>Telefon kontaktowy: <input class="xForm"  type="text" name="telefon_firmy" value=""/>
<p>Osoba do kontaktu: <input class="xForm"  type="text" name="osoba_firmy" value="" />
<p>Email: <input class="xForm"  type="text" name="email_firmy" value=""/>
<p><b>Planowany termin realizacji inwestycji: <input class="xForm"  type="text" name="data_inwestycji" id="datepicker" value=""/></b>
</div>
<div id="sekcja2" class="sekcja">
<div class="headerx"><p><b>Dane na temat formy preferowanej wyceny:</b></p></div>
<p>Wstępna wycena <input class="xForm"  type="checkbox" name="wycena_wstepna" checked="" />
<p>Wycena docelowa z rzutem urządzeń <input class="xForm"  type="checkbox" name="wycena_zrzutem" checked=""  />
<br />
<!---// More form data more input fields //--->
</form>
```

My PHP code is:

```
<?php
$url = file_get_contents('/wycena.html');
$url = mb_convert_encoding($url, 'utf-8', mb_detect_encoding($url));
$url = mb_convert_encoding($url, 'html-entities', 'utf-8'); 
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($url);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$html = $dom->saveHTML();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

// in this case i have fill only one field of input by name "nazwa_firmy" //and value "testtest" only for testing

//=======================================================
$key="nazwa_firmy"; //name of input element - test data
$val="testest";     //value of input element - test data
//=======================================================

$item = $xpath->query('//input[@name = "'.$key.'"]/@type');

if($item[0]->nodeValue=="text"){
$itemx = $xpath->query('//input[@name = "'.$key.'"]/@value');
}

if($item[0]->nodeValue=="checkbox"){
$itemx = $xpath->query('//input[@name = "'.$key.'"]/@checked');
}

$itemx[0]->nodeValue = $val;

echo $html = $dom->saveHTML();
?>
```

Why is it not possible to fill in the form in this way, is there any method to fill it in?

Comment: You have to fill the values into the **value=""** fields. By the way: I do not see any database connection or query in the script?

Comment: I know that, but I don't know how to fill value with XPatch and DOM parser. I have already written similar scripts to translate HTML into different languages and Xpatch did the job, unfortunately it didn't work out in this case.

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? Do you want to create static copies of this form page, with the fields pre-filled with the respective values? Or do you actually want to _submit_ this form, with the given values? For the latter, you should probably not mess around with DOM parsing in the first place (assuming the form structure is static, and does not need to be “analyzed” first every single time), but rather make the according POST request to the endpoint directly.

Comment: I want to fill in the form with data from a table downloaded from the database - I have the name of the field to be filled in the database and its value - although I can generate the form manually, it is troublesome because it requires a lot of input. Originally this html form was used to send POST requests - and now I would like this form to be filled with the received data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aleady have $array containing the values, just echo them  inside the value attrubute of the form:  -

```html
<p>Nazwa firmy: <input class="xForm"  type="text" name="nazwa_firmy" value="<?= $array [nazwa_firmy] ?>"/>
<p>Adres: <input class="xForm"  type="text" name="adres_firmy" value="<?= $array [adres_firmy] ?>"/>
<p>Kraj: <input class="xForm"  type="text" name="kraj_firmy" value="<?= $array [kraj_firmy] ?>"/>
<p>Telefon kontaktowy: <input class="xForm"  type="text" name="telefon_firmy" value="<?= $array [telefon_firmy] ?>"/>
<p>Osoba do kontaktu: <input class="xForm"  type="text" name="osoba_firmy" value="<?= $array [osoba_firmy] ?>" />
<p>Email: <input class="xForm"  type="text" name="email_firmy" value="<?= $array [email_firmy] ?>"/>
<p><b>Planowany termin realizacji inwestycji: <input class="xForm"  type="text" name="data_inwestycji" id="datepicker" value="<?= $array [data_inwestycji] ?>"/></b>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, I can do it like that, but I thought it could be done automatically, because I have over 150 fields to fill in, it's a pity that it cannot be otherwise.

Comment: _Well, I can do it like that, but I thought it could be done automatically, because I have over 150 fields to fill in_  

With Copy paste this is less then 5 minutes  of work -maybe much less than you already investied in thinking of alternate solutions - and  a simple  solution easy to understand and debug  Always avoid solutions you do not understand.  

Just copy paste or replace **value=""**
by **value="<?= $array [xxx] ?>"**   then douible click on the id and replace the xxx by the string from id -  **I would say this should be LESS than 5 minutes.**  and less time i spent here :-)

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.